# What is **error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe** in Odoo?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-15

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('192.168.15.184', 44813)Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/SocketServer.py", line 593, in process_request_thread self.finish_request(request, client_address)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/SocketServer.py", line 651, in __init__ self.finish()

  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/SocketServer.py", line 704, in finish self.wfile.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 303, in flush self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])

**error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe**
```

I think there is some issue with odoo.conf. Any idea?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Errno+32+Broken+pipe -- just basic research. Further, your question should include a [mcve]. As a new user, also read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58937394/7045119

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It indicates that your connection to server is lost.

You can follow the steps below to solve it.

1. Recheck your `.conf` file whether the port is missing or not.
2. Reload your Odoo instance.